# SAML2 Metadata - Multiple Signing Certificates

Tags: saml, adfs, shibboleth, service-provider

I'm looking at a SAML IdP's metadata and it lists three unique certificates - 2 signing and 1 encryption.

```xml
    ...   
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    ...
```

I understand why it lists a signing and encryption certificate, but how do I determine which signing certificate to use in my service provider? Why are there two signing certificates at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ADFS e.g. has two certificates for rollover from secondary to primary. There is a period when both are valid. You can use either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When the IDP is changing it's signing certificates it first publishes the new certificate in parallell with the old certificate in the metadata. When the idp actually switches over to using the new certificate, all SPs must know of the new certificate, or they will not be able to validate the signatures.

As an SP you have no idea of where in the process the IDP is, so you have to check if the signature validates to any of the two listed certificates.

Comment: What if IdP keeps introducing new certificates? The only option I see is to fetch signing x509 from federation metadata's public URL, but what if the URL is not publicly accessible?

Comment: and when signing an authnrequest, which is better to use, the first or the second?

Answer (score 1):

Another reason you might (always) see two is that you might have one coming from a backchannel certificate (eg. credentials/idp-backchannel.crt and credentials/idp-signing.crt)

I think there are many SPs that don't really know what to do there. If you don't need backchannel, you might consider removing it (or at least not handing it to people in your curated metadata).

The annoying (really annoying) thing in my experience is that all three are separate certificates about the same thing (at least in my case), and all three are valid at the same time (this will surely lead to difficulties).

As per https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Installation :

The installation process will suggest or generate the following information for you:

(begin quote)

- the IdP's entityID (which you can override as noted above)
- separate self-signed key/certificate pairs for:

  - **message signing**
  - **securing web service connections, generally on port 8443**
  - **encryption of data by other systems for decryption by the IdP**
- a secret key and key version file for securing cookies and other data produced by the IdP for its own use (this is a special Java keystore of type "JCEKS")
- some initial sample metadata describing the IdP for use by partner SPs, once it's reviewed and supplemented
- a default set of IdP configuration files based on this information

(end quote)