# Is there a way to configure SimpleSAMLphp SP metadata with two certificates?

Tags: simplesamlphp

We run a SimpleSAMLphp IDP, and one of the SP's it is configured for (Cloudflare) provides multiple certificates in [their public metadata](https://wycliffe.cloudflareaccess.com/cdn-cgi/access/saml-metadata), both of which have the exact same expiration date/time.

Normally, we would simply put the SP's certificate data into the `certData` attribute in the metadata for that SP.

Is there a way to configure multiple certificates for an SP?

Looking at the SimpleSAMLphp [documentation for SP metadata](https://github.com/silinternational/ssp-hub-production/pull/19), I don't see a way to do so.

I also reviewed [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909251/saml2-metadata-multiple-signing-certificates), but it is about an IDP providing multiple certificates, rather than an SP providing multiple certificates, and I didn't see any clues there that helped me figure out an answer to this issue. There was also [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/simplesamlphp/c/RDArP5WxD18) on one of the SSP mailing lists about multiple certs for an IDP (support was added in SSP 1.7.0), but it also does not seem to answer my question.